# conditionally set background color of a dynamically created textbox from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP,NET page with between 50 to 200 dynamically created texboxes arranged in a grid. Each textbox accepts a number if items to order.
I have to use a web service to check qty levels so when the btnPostBack is clicked I call a function that checks stock levels via the web service.
If the stock level is low, I want to set the textbax background color to yellow from the VB code behind. I will stop the post and return out of the postback function for the user to see which items are out of stock(this part I know how to handle). 
Problem is, I cant figure how to reference the text box since it was created dynamically from codebehind itself. It has a unique ID, such as,"tbX0700709686X-10X0" and I know the ID when the stock level is checked. However, as expected, I get compile errors from VB because the textboxes do not exist at design time.

```
 Dim stockLevel As Integer = Helper.checkQTY(arySub(1))
            If stockLevel < xQty Then
              tbX0700709686X-10X0.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
                 ...
```

How do I reference my control(tbX0700709686X-10X0) when VB isn't aware it exists at design time?

Comment: I apologize if you've tried this already, but for a similar scenario, I've used FindControl (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). You may need to tinker to find the right parent control to use for thisParentControl.FindControl("myControlIdHere") but it's worked for me.

Comment: Meghan, I will try this as soon as possible. New problem came up that has demanded my attention.